# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Regions can not be created in a locator

Tags: geode

```
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
    if(Locator.hasLocator()) {
        Locator l = Locator.getLocator();
        System.out.println("Name of the locator running is: "+l.asString());
    }else {
        LocatorLauncher locatorLauncher = new 

        LocatorLauncher.Builder().setMemberName("mylocator").
        setPort(13334).build();
        locatorLauncher.start();
        ServerLauncher serverLauncher = new 
        ServerLauncher.Builder().setMemberName("myserver").
        setServerPort(40404).
        set("sta rt-locator", "localhost[13334]").build();
        System.out.println(serverLauncher.getMemberName());
    }

    Cache myCache = new CacheFactory().create();
    System.out.println("Cache created");
    Region<String, String> myRegion = myCache.<String, 
    String>createRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.REPLICATE).create("region");
    myRegion.put("1","One");
    myRegion.put("2","Two");
}
```

I get this error when executing the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Regions can not be created in a locator.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand a little bit on why you want to launch the locator using the `LocatorLauncher`? Locators are only meant for member discovery, so I think that is a valid exception.

For getting started, I would simply use `gfsh` (from the /bin directory of your geode installation) to start the locator and then create the regions:

```
$ gfsh
gfsh> start locator
gfsh> start server
gfsh> create region --name=hello --type=REPLICATE
```

Then write a simple client to access the data as detailed on [this wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/#Index-Geodein5minutesGeodein5minutes).

Comment: I am new to Geode and in the initial stages of learning.  I could do the above mentioned from gfsh without any problems.  Though there is no special purpose other than getting familiar with API , I tried to create the same stuff using API and got the exception and was clueless on why. Please confirm if it cannot be done the way I did.

Comment: Got your point and could create from gfsh without any problems.